# What is the ADF v2 equivalent of WindowStart?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We are migrating from ADF V1 to ADF V2. Our pipelines are scheduled to run daily and we have that part of V2 working. A pipeline will start at the appointed time.

My question is how do I pass the time that the scheduled trigger is scheduled to start into the where clause of a select statement in a copy activity? I suspect I've overlooked or misread some documentation, but I just can't figure it out.

No matter what I try, the variable does not seem to evaluate at runtime. So, the where clause looks something like this when it runs:
where last_update>=’@pipeline().TriggerTime’
And obviously @pipeline().TriggerTime is not a date.

I’ve pulled this list of parameters to try from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables

This is what worked in V1:
"sqlReaderQuery": "$$Text.Format('select columns from table where last_update>=\'{0:yyyy-MM-dd}\'', WindowStart, WindowEnd)"

Things I've tried:

-- Passing @trigger().scheduledTime in as a parameter in the trigger to @{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.startDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')} in the where clause with a parameter in the pipeline defined as startDate of type string.

-- Setting @pipeline().TriggerTime as the default value for the pipeline().parameters.startDate.

-- Calling @pipeline().TriggerTime in the where clause.

Many thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

### Pipeline Source

```
{
    "name": "PL_ADLS_RAW_IDMTables_DAILY",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "isStartDateNotNull",
                "description": "If the startDate parameter == 0 then run the full load. If the startDate parameter != 0 then run for >= startDate parameter.",
                "type": "IfCondition",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@equals(pipeline().parameters.startDate,'0')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "ifFalseActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "copy_ENTITY_FULL",
                            "description": "Copies ENTITY from IDM Database to ADLS Raw Zone",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 60,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "SqlSource",
                                    "sqlReaderQuery": {
                                        "value": "SELECT [ENTITY_ID],[ENTITY_TYPE_ID],REPLACE(REPLACE([SHORT_NAME], CHAR(13),' '), CHAR(10),' '),REPLACE(REPLACE([ENTITY_NAME], CHAR(13),' '), CHAR(10),' '),REPLACE(REPLACE([ENTITY_DESCRIPTION], CHAR(13),' '), CHAR(10),' '),REPLACE(REPLACE([STATUS], CHAR(13),' '), CHAR(10),' '),[STATUS_DATE],[REVISION_ID],[CREATED_BY],[CREATION_DATE],[LAST_UPDATED_BY],[LAST_UPDATE_DATE],REPLACE(REPLACE([COMMENTS], CHAR(13),' '), CHAR(10),' ') FROM [dbo].[ENTITY] where LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= '@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.startDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')}'",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreSink"
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "dataIntegrationUnits": 0
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "DS_IN_SQL_IDM_ENTITY",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "DS_OUT_ADLS_RAW_IDM_ENTITY",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "ifTrueActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "copy_ENTITY",
                            "description": "Copies ENTITY from IDM Database to ADLS Raw Zone",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 60,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "SqlSource",
                                    "sqlReaderQuery": {
                                        "value": "SELECT [ENTITY_ID],[ENTITY_TYPE_ID],REPLACE(REPLACE([SHORT_NAME], CHAR(13),' '), CHAR(10),' '),REPLACE(REPLACE([ENTITY_NAME], CHAR(13),' '), CHAR(10),' '),REPLACE(REPLACE([ENTITY_DESCRIPTION], CHAR(13),' '), CHAR(10),' '),REPLACE(REPLACE([STATUS], CHAR(13),' '), CHAR(10),' '),[STATUS_DATE],[REVISION_ID],[CREATED_BY],[CREATION_DATE],[LAST_UPDATED_BY],[LAST_UPDATE_DATE],REPLACE(REPLACE([COMMENTS], CHAR(13),' '), CHAR(10),' ') FROM [dbo].[ENTITY]",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreSink"
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "dataIntegrationUnits": 0
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "DS_IN_SQL_IDM_ENTITY",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "DS_OUT_ADLS_RAW_IDM_ENTITY",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "startDate": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

### Trigger Source:

```
{
    "name": "TR_SCHED_0800EST",
    "properties": {
        "description": "Daily 0800 EST",
        "runtimeState": "Stopped",
        "pipelines": [
            {
                "pipelineReference": {
                    "referenceName": "PL_ADLS_RAW_IDMTables_DAILY",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "startDate": "@trigger().scheduledTime"
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Day",
                "interval": 1,
                "startTime": "2018-08-30T13:00:00Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC",
                "schedule": {
                    "minutes": [
                        0
                    ],
                    "hours": [
                        13
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT

This works

[image]

This does not work

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Passing @trigger().scheduledTime in as a parameter in the trigger to @{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.startDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')} in the where clause with a parameter in the pipeline defined as startDate of type string. 
is the right way.

When you edit the trigger in the UI,
Make sure you pass value in the following way.
[image]

Comment: That results in the following error. 

"In function 'formatDateTime', the value provided for date time string '@trigger().scheduledTime' was not valid. The datetime string must match ISO 8601 format"

This is the where clause. Perhaps this is the source of the error?
LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= '@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.startDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')}'

Comment: I also found this thread on MSDN:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9541b52e-c79e-4e02-b473-acbdfd88f365/dynamic-variable-in-url-in-azure-data-factory-v2?forum=AzureDataFactory

Comment: Could you share both pipeline json and trigger json payload? Looks like you put the value into the default value?

Comment: I updated the original post with the code for pipeline and trigger. THANK YOU!

Comment: Actually your pipeline looks fine to me? What if you click the trigger now and pass a ISO format string value?

Comment: And where did you find the error message? Could you give a screenshot?

Comment: your pipeline is right. And the error message indicates the expression is not evaluated. Did you use rerun of a previous run? You should not use that. Because the previous parameters value will be used directly. I suggest you could create a new trigger with the “new/edit” trigger button.

Comment: And I also noticed that your trigger is not in stopped state.

Comment: I have been using Trigger Now for testing. Also, the trigger is in a stopped state to prevent recurring failures.

Comment: I agree. It appears that the trigger expression is not being evaluated since passing in a proper date string works, but not the expression.

Comment: Hi there, as Fang Liu mentioned above, don't click Trigger Now and pass "@trigger().scheduledTime" to run the pipeline, please Click New/Edit, select the trigger and then pass "@trigger().scheduledTime" to the pipeline parameter, in this way you're using the Scheduled Trigger to fire your pipeline run and "@trigger().scheduledTime" will be resolved as an expression not plain text. The same issue in MSDN thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9541b52e-c79e-4e02-b473-acbdfd88f365/dynamic-variable-in-url-in-azure-data-factory-v2?forum=AzureDataFactory  has been resolved.